# How to receive blob response for downloading excel file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to download a model in an excel file using angular, this is function the code of my service :

```
getExcelReport(data: myModel[]): Observable<Blob> {
 let params = new HttpParams()
      .set('myParam', JSON.stringify(data));

return this.Http.get(this.url + '/MyController/GetExcelReport', { params: params, observe: "body", responseType: "blob" });
```

when i call it i get an error : 415 (Unsupported Media Type).
Any i idea of the correct syntax to use?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a serverside issue?

Comment: this what i have in server side controller`  [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetExcelReport")] public async Task<IActionResult> GetExcelReport([FromBody] IList<myModelType> myModel)`

Comment: What do you actually want after receiving the file..? Do you want the user to simply download it? If so, a window.open might be much easier. If you need more (like setting auth headers in the request), maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335807/how-to-download-an-excel-file-in-angular-8-as-an-api-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, yes i want only download it.I found this solution:

```
getExcelReport(data: myModel[]): void {
    const url: string = this.url  + '/MyController/GetExcelReport';
    this.Http.post(url, data, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe((response: Blob) => saveAs(response, `report.xlsx`));
  }
```

In API:

```
 [HttpPost] [Route("GetExcelReport")] public async Task<IActionResult> GetExcelReport([FromBody] IList<myModelType> myModel)
```

It worked for me